# Is this a bug with the comment markdown syntax?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)

Here's a comment I left on a post earlier:

```
The only thing is that I was wanting to assemble bytecode, not *dis*assemble it. :-)
```

I put the asterisks around dis because I wanted those three letters to be italicized.  Should they have been?

Comment: Related question - loosely - how do you get back-ticks into running text?  Makes annotating shell scripts hard - the only way I've found is to put the text into a code block.  But that can interrupt the flow of a paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It won't work in the middle of words.

It's part of the [Three Markdown Gotchas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/).

Comment: I'm sad now.  :-(