# Should be able to bold and italicise parts of words

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)

Just as the title says, why can't we italicize or bold parts of text?

For example, on SuperUser I tried to say this:

> Took a hard look at the speed test and the upload, and it is (just now) 0.94 M**b**/s while the upload is 124 K**B**/s

(strange, that [in the origional comment](https://superuser.com/questions/156982/uploading-kill-internet-connection/156990#156990), it didn't italicise at all)

As you can see, for things like MB vs Mb and for many many other things, this could be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Took a hard look at the speed test and the upload, and it is (just now) 0.94 M**b**s while the upload is 124 K**B**s.

Use HTML tags instead of markdown, in these situations. I used <b> in this, for example. ([link to source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/0f0be998-31cd-41a4-808c-208276c89f0f/view-source))

Comment: This was a comment, and according to the sandbox, you can't do that. See the 2nd to last comment here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: @Lord Sorry. You never specified you were asking only about comments in your question, nor was it tagged as such, so I answered for text in post bodies. To answer the question of comments, though, no HTML is supported in comments, only a very limitted amount of Markdown. [Buggy markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51417/bug-using-the-markdown-in-comments), too, when it comes to inline stuff in comments.

Comment: @Lord [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words/19004#19004) from Jeff states that there are no plans to allow intra-word emphasis in markdown, so by extension it'll never be possible in comments as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can, see my example below:

> H**i** my n*am*e is Ju***stin*** Nelson.

You just have to use the `<b>` and `<i>` html tags.

Comment: Source view: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/cece6727-c16e-4bb4-9c87-595de8a9dd03/view-source

Comment: Does not work in comments, 2nd to last comment here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: Ops, yeah, it isn't supported in comments at all...my bad. (@lord)