# Bold does not work inside words

Tags: bug, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)

This is a simple bug: You can't make individual letters in a word bold.

### Example:

```
**SVG** stands for **S**calable **V**ector **G**raphics
```

> **SVG** stands for **S**calable **V**ector **G**raphics

### Dirty(?) Workaround:

I found a workaround that uses the Unicode character "Zero-Width Joiner" to separate the letters from the rest of the word code-wise, but not visually.

```
**SVG** stands for **S**&zwj;calable **V**&zwj;ector **G**&zwj;raphics
```

> **SVG** stands for **S**‍calable **V**‍ector **G**‍raphics

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55493/should-be-able-to-bold-and-italicise-parts-of-words

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that's a bug. I'm pretty sure that's just how Markdown works.

You can revert to good ol' HTML.

> **SVG** stands for **S**calable **V**ector **G**raphics

```
**SVG** stands for <b>S</b>calable <b>V</b>ector <b>G</b>raphics
```

You could also add a space behind the letters. [Not perfect, but "good enough"](http://lifehacker.com/5585049/the-perfect-is-the-enemy-of-the-good).

> **SVG** stands for **S** calable **V** ector **G** raphics

```
**SVG** stands for **S** calable **V** ector **G** raphics
```

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be a bug; it recognizes the asterisks for italics, but not for bold.

Comment: I think it's more that it throws away the outermost asterisks from markdown and parses them literally.

Comment: @Supuhstar there has to be a non alphanumeric character after the last * for it to be treated Bold/Italic. If you'd written `*S*calable` you would have got *S*calable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#italics-bold mentions nothing of this behavior. It's either a bug or an undocumented "feature". When behavior such as this is undocumented, I tend to consider it a bug.

Comment: [From the horse's mouth](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19004/21960): "We don't support intra-word emphasis. This is by design."

Comment: Whatever you do, do not put random blanks into words. I will stalk you and edit the hell out of your stuff. You will not be happy. Do not break English to paint over a dumb shortcoming of a piece of software. You're a programmer, for crying out loud. How would you react if I told you that `$vector` is the same as `$v ector` — not perfect, but good enough?

Answer (score 5):

This is largely because this is a website about coding, and having something like "var_with_underscores" render as "var‍*with*‍underscores" is more annoying than using workarounds. Because of it, this "bug" will not be "fixed".

### Workarounds include:

Use the Unicode Zero-Width Joiner: (uses 5 extra characters per instance, works for all Markdown formatting types)

```
**SVG** stands for **S**&zwj;calable **V**&zwj;ector **G**&zwj;raphics
```

> **SVG** stands for **S**‍calable **V**‍ector **G**‍raphics

Use plain HTML: (uses 3 extra characters per instance, must know HTML)

```
**SVG** stands for <b>S</b>calable <b>V</b>ector <b>G</b>raphics
```

> **SVG** stands for **S**calable **V**ector **G**raphics