# Italicizing words that include an underscore doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editor

Here's the screenshot of my experience with italic text over Stack Overflow.

[image: screenshot]

Basically it just wraps the word into asterisks and leaves it like this. *Here on Meta I do not observe this bug.*

Comment: It's because underscore `_` also delimits italic. `_italic_` -> _italic_

Comment: As a workaround for @Chris' comment: use `*unique\_names*` or `_unique\_names_` instead. (So: escape using a backslash.) I wonder if this is expected behavior though!

Comment: `*unique\_names*` -> *unique\_names* (just to prove it works)

Comment: For me, it's the same on Meta.

Comment: Are you sure about your "Here on Meta I do not observe this bug"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As ChrisF said, the problem is the underscore. `_` is a control character, and control characters might behave differently from what you expect.

Just escape the underscore (`\_`) and it will work:

```
*unique\_names*
```

results in

> *unique_names*

Comment: Still, I wonder if this is expected. On SE sites, emphasis [within a word](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#em) (intra-word emphasis) is [explicitly disabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words/19004#19004), to avoid emphasis of _dear_ in `hello_dear_world`. That said, maybe the expected behavior is that asterisks and underscores in words are totally ignored, and escaping would not be needed?

Comment: The current behavior is certainly not what I would expect. For starters, `*_*` results in an italic underscore.

Comment: Hehe, I hope you had to peek into the HTML source to tell that the underscore is (told to be) rendered italic for `*_*`? Spot the difference: _ versus *_* ;-)

Comment: So you **can't** tell the difference?

Comment: I even zoomed in, [but: no](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dcaOP.png). :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is this a discrepancy between the JavaScript preview and the rendered post? Let's see:

*unique_names*

No, so they are at least consistent.

I agree it's not exactly what I would expect to happen.

*unique*names*

provides a similar but .. more logical .. result as [we disable intra-word emphasis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words/19004#19004), so perhaps the regex just treats `*_` as part of the same character group.

Answer (score 1):

This is [fixed in the next build](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229236/115866).