# Italic button in editor does nothing for partial words

Tags: bug, markdown, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)
>   [Bolding words that include an underscore doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119850/bolding-words-that-include-an-underscore-doesnt-work)

If in a Stack Overflow question or answer text area I write

> unchanged

and then attempt to emphasise the 'un' prefix, by selecting those two letters and pushing the 'I' button on the toolbar, it just shows up as

> *un*changed

Of course, I'd expect the italic button to give me some syntax that renders as

> *un*changed

Comment: See the answer given from Jeff Atwood for that question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno These questions aren't duplicates. If a part of Jeff's answer addresses this question, it should be mentioned in an answer here.