# How can I italicize text that contain underscores?

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bolding words that include an underscore doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119850/bolding-words-that-include-an-underscore-doesnt-work)
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)

I was writing an answer on StackExchange and found that when you use asterisk around content with underscores, e.g. `*I_Love_StackExchange*` it simply doesn't make it italic.

I suppose this is because the underscores at the beginning and the end are also used to make content italic.

They look like this:

- *I_Love_StackExchange*
- _I_Love_StackExchange_

Does anyone know a way to italicize text that contains underscores?

Comment: @Arjan - I'm not totally sure it's a dupe. It seems like the system *could* reasonably italicize whole words which *contain* markdown even if it doesn't support markdown *within* words

Comment: You' right, @Brad, I don't know how I used that post for the duplicate! I was looking for Jeff's statement about the support for intra-word markdown, which he mentioned in [Bolding words that include an underscore doesn't work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119850/bolding-words-that-include-an-underscore-doesnt-work), and somehow followed to that post. Still then, it's surely a dupe of the latter. (In which my comments to the accepted answer state exactly what you're stating.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're just confusing the Markdown parser. Try escaping them:

- **`*I\_Love\_StackExchange*`**

  > *I_Love_StackExchange*
- **`_I\_Love\_StackExchange_`**

  > *I_Love_StackExchange*

Comment: But, is this documented, and hence: future proof?

Answer (score 6):

*I_Love_StackExchange* Works.

You just have to escape the underscores with a backslash. That is:

```
*I\_Love\_StackExchange*
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the standard HTML `<i>` tag:

```
<i>I_Love_StackExchange</i>
```

whichs renders as:

*I_Love_StackExchange*

---

Here's `<em>` for comparison:

```
<em>I_Love_StackExchange</em>
```

should look the same as `<i>` on SE:

*I_Love_StackExchange*

Note though, that [they do not have to be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939807/strong-vs-font-weightbold-em-vs-font-styleitalic)

Comment: Thanks! or `<em>`, right?

Comment: In this case yes, but they [aren't always the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939807/strong-vs-font-weightbold-em-vs-font-styleitalic)

Comment: `<i>` does not render as italic on mobile. In fact, it does not show any special styling at all. `<em>` does though.

Comment: @Arjan that sounds a bug you should report then, I don't believe `<i>` has been blacklisted or anything