# Italics markup is not working on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bolding words that include an underscore doesn’t work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119850/bolding-words-that-include-an-underscore-doesnt-work)
>   [How can I italicize text that contain underscores?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147117/how-can-i-italicize-text-that-contain-underscores)

In one of my Stack Overflow questions, *[ParentReference or Google_ParentReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837396)*, I typed the following.

> It is seems that there are some prefix "Google_" added and ParentReference is renamed to *Google_ParentReference*.

I expected *Google_ParentReference* would be in italic, but it didn't come in italic. The star is still with it. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is an *underscore* character ( `_` ) between two words. So Instead of `*` use `<I>` tag for it like this:

> It is seems that there are some prefix "Google_" added and
>   ParentReference is renamed to *Google_ParentReference*.

Comment: Can give any reference to the markup?

Comment: @habeebperwad - Go to [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also see [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/187824)

Comment: You can also escape the underscore: `*Google\_ParentReference*` => *Google\_ParentReference*