# Bug (or feature-request) when attempting to use bold text in URLs

Tags: feature-request, bug, markdown, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)

I was writing [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9418487/1210983), and in that answer I was trying to highlight some text in this URL by making it bold. Here's how it went:

`http://x**[channel]**x.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml`

Shouldn't **[channel]** show up in bold? I realize this might be a limitation with what I assume is the regex converting the URLs OR making the text bold. However, it would be nice if we had a way of highlighting text in URLs. Is there a way to do this that I don't know about?