# Italic text next to normal text with no spaces in between

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)

Is it possible to have an italic character next to some non-italic text so that there's no spaces in between?

For example, I want an italic *a* but normal numbers:

> a1556

If I make the *a* italic and then write the numbers immediately after I get this:

> *a*1556

It works with a space in between, but that's not what I want:

> *a* 1556

Comment: I read this title and thought to myself, "cats and dogs, living together!"

Comment: ^__ I read **that** and thought to myself... `"w00t??"` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular html tags for italics here. Either of these:

```
<em>a</em>1556
<i>a</i>1556
```

Yields:

*a*1556

Comment: I accepted this answer as it's easier to remember than the zero width Unicode character.

Answer (score 5):

I've come across this a few times and the solution is relatively simple...

I use a zero width Unicode character between the last asterisk and the next character -

*a*​123

This will also work for **B**​O​**L**​D characters...

---

Here is the zero width character (between the brackets).

```
(​)
```

---

For ease of use, I made myself a little JavaScript bookmarklet that `"displays"` an alert with the character inside -

`javascript: alert("%E2%80%8B");`

Comment: So, the cats and dogs aren't actually living together, but they just look like it? ;-)

Comment: Unicode animals are not very sociable, but they have to keep up appearances for the other domesticated house pets... So yes... Your assumption is correct.

Comment: "He tossed his auburn mane majestically, and resumed warily eyeing his canine counterpart from across the zero-width Unicode character which separated pack from pride..." I'll stick to my day job, methinks! Hehe

Comment: 'Tis a more helpful/elegant answer than those already posted to the duplicate question. Might I motivate you to post it there?

Comment: @the - sure, I don't see why not. :P  How would you suggest going about it?  I don't want to brutally copy-paste across posts... Should I delete this answer and post it there?  Thin this answer out and post the full version there?

Comment: I'd copy and paste... Does that make me brutal?

Comment: Well its the **definition** of a duplicate post :P This post is already closed so it might not be too bad... Here I go! Thanks for the compliment BTW!