# Bold Formatting and Full Stops

Tags: feature-request, bug, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)

I'm having problems trying to embolden the suffix of text such as 'config.properties' (including the full stop)

Expected: 
config **.properties** (without the whitespace between g and .)

Result:

config**.properties**