# How to put italic and then an "s"?

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words)

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705360/setting-style-on-two-component-types/13705416#comment18831619_13705416) I noticed that the OP used the following syntax.'

```
*h1*s
```

I changed it to *h1*'s but it's technically not correct English. Also, I'm curious how to handle it.

Comment: @Bart Your assumption is correct. I didn't find that answer myself. (WMD? How did you look for it, mate?!)

Comment: I'm always looking for WMDs......but in this case I searched "markdown inside words" remembering an earlier dupe. <--- Long story short, I spend far too much time here.

Comment: In this case I'd use `h1`s, since the `<h1>` tag is code.

Comment: Yeah, or I abuse a hyphen in such cases: h1-s

Comment: @CodesInChaos **That** doesn't look right. Did you intend to leave the space there?

Comment: @Bart Shame on you! Go and wash your keyboard with soap! Spend some time [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/) instead! :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I would, if only I could speak English. But I can't. Not a word.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Which space? The margins of inline code are a bit larger than I'd like, but I still think it's the semantically correct choice.

Comment: @Bart I see, I see. In that case I will type slowly so you get what I say. :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos On my screen it sure looks like "h1 s". But I think I know what you mean. Since I can't edit your comment, I can't see the source code for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it for you.

```
This will target **all** <i>h1</i>s and <i>p</i>s.
```

> This will target **all** *h1*s and *p*s.

Markdown is not perfect. It does a fantastic job *almost* all the time.